# android studio flutter source dart code analysis error

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

why android studio open flutter source code analysis error. my own code don't have error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ztKp.png)

no errors, like my own code.

Comment: I can close analyze in editor, right click, analyze -> configure current file analysis, hightling level set to none.

Comment: The error message is not very clear and requires further explanation. Instead of using an image, it would be better to share your source code. I recommend running the following commands on your terminal: "flutter clean" and "flutter pub get". These commands will clean your project and retrieve the necessary dependencies for your Flutter application. Once you have run these commands, try running your application again and see if the error message has been resolved.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Comment: It's not code error, just ide static check error, I don't know where to config the check or analyze or something else.